# Is getChildFragmentManager required in setFragmentResultListener when multiple fragments are placed in FragmentStateAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

We are using the following to retrieve result from `DialogFragment` based on https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#test

```
private void select() {
    SelectDialogFragment selectDialogFragment = SelectDialogFragment.newInstance();
    selectDialogFragment.show(getParentFragmentManager(), SELECT_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
}

private void initFragmentResultListener() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(SelectDialogFragment.SELECT_DIALOG_FRAGMENT_RESULT, getViewLifecycleOwner(), (requestKey, result) -> {
        ...
    });
}
```

However, the above code will not work correctly if multiple fragments are placed in `androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter`.

**For instance, if 2nd visible fragment is showing a `DialogFragment`, the 1st invisible fragment will obtain the result mistakenly.**

After some trial and error, we notice we need to fix such a problem by using `getChildFragmentManager`

```
private void select() {
    SelectDialogFragment selectDialogFragment = SelectDialogFragment.newInstance();
    selectDialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), SELECT_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
}

private void initFragmentResultListener() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(SelectDialogFragment.SELECT_DIALOG_FRAGMENT_RESULT, getViewLifecycleOwner(), (requestKey, result) -> {
        ...
    });
}
```

I was wondering, is such an approach a correct way to fix the problem? *Since I seldom see `getChildFragmentManager` being used in official example, I am not confident in my solution.*

My first impression is that, even if we are using `getParentFragmentManager`, the `getViewLifecycleOwner` should prevent 1st invisible fragment from getting the result. But that is not the case.

Since it is difficult to determine when a fragment will be placed under `ViewPager` in the future, it is OK to just use `getChildFragmentManager` all over the place when using `setFragmentResultListener`, to prevent dialog fragment's result sent to a wrong fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **always** be using `getChildFragmentManager` for a `DialogFragment` as explained in the [DialogFragment guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs#showing):

> When creating a DialogFragment from within a Fragment, you must use the Fragment's child FragmentManager to ensure that the state is properly restored after configuration changes.
>
> ```
> new PurchaseConfirmationDialogFragment().show(
>       getChildFragmentManager(), PurchaseConfirmationDialog.TAG);
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I have been doing wrongly all the while.

Comment: I think I know the reason why we are not using getChildFragmentManager all the while. It will cause the following exception - "declared target fragment ... that does not belong to this FragmentManager!", if we are using setTargetFragment (which is currently deprecated)

Comment: Yes, that API has been deprecated since April 2020.